# GDB - Accessing real and imaginary parts of a complex number

Tags: c++, c, gdb, complex-numbers

When debugging a program which uses  (either C or C++), `gdb` displays complex numbers as `_M_value =  xxx + yyy*I` (with a type of `complex double`).

While debugging, I need to print that number multiplied by a factor.

The following *does not* work:

```
print a * 8.0
```

I get `Argument to arithmetic operation not a number or boolean`.

Also, I cannot access the *real and imaginary parts* so that I can write a gdb macro to do the above. My current solution is to write a C function for manipulating complex values and arrays, and calling that function from gdb. Somehow, this just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Do you use the standard C++ complex template ? if yes, is a.real() / a.imaj() not working ?

Comment: @neuro: thanks - .real() and .imag() methods work.

Comment: you are welcome. I've set my comment in an answer to help people (was it to gain reputation ? ^^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the standard C++ complex template then complex::real() and complex::imaj() should work.

my2c

Note : Was a comment ^^

Comment: Still annoying that gdb does not allow arithmetic using complex numbers (i.e., multiplying by scalar). Perhaps gdb 7 with python support will help.

Comment: @nimrod: yes. I always feel a bit frustrated when using gdb to explore complex object/template structures with gdb ... i hope gdb 7 will improve that ...

Answer (score 0):

You can call the C library functions `creal()` and `cimag()` to break down the number.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Prints 0 for real and imaginary parts. But I'm using c++, so if I use the .rea() and .imag() method on the C++ object (not the _m_value) I get the desired result.